# Create array inside a function and use it outside

Tags: c, embedded, i2c

I'm working on a project, where I use the I2C-Interface of a microcontroller.
At the beginning I want to scan the I2C-Bus for sensors, because I don't know how many of the sensors are connected (different addresses)

Depending on the address of the found device, I want to create a structure with the device specific parameters.

Is it possible to use the struct outside of the scan function?
Or is there a better way to solve this problem during runtime, like creating an global array and add a `bool found`?

I'd like to have something like:

```
struct sensorA sensorA[];
struct sensorB sensorB[];


for (int i = 0; i < 127; i++){
  err_code = send_i2c_dummy(address);
  if (err_code == 0) { ​//found device
   ​ switch(address){
      case 0x10:
        // append element to array sensorA;
        break;
      case 0x11:
        // append element to array sensorA;
        break;
      case 0x66:
        // append element to array sensorB;
        break;
      case 0x67:
        // append element to array sensorB;
        break;
      default: 
        printf("found unknown device\n");
        break;
    }
  }
}
```

Is it possible to do it like this:

```
uint32_t create_SensorA_array(){

  uint8_t i;
  i = get_number_of_sensorA()
  struct sensorA array[i] = malloc(i * sizeof(struct sensorA));

  return array;
}


uint8_t get_number_of_sensorA(){
  uint8_t number = 0;

  uint8_t addresses[4]= {0x10,0x11,0x12,0x13};
  for(i = 0; i <= 4; i++){
    err_code = send_i2c_dummy(address);
    if (err_code == 0) {
      number++;
    }
  }

  return number;
}
```

Would this work in a function?
I'd like to return the pointer address of the array.
How do I know the size of the array when I just return the pointer adress?

Thank you

Comment: `sensorA[] sensorA;
sensorB[] sensorB;` it is not C language.

Comment: I do not understand your concern. You are not returning any pointer from the function.

Comment: Dynamic memory obtained from `malloc` is still valid after the function exits. So just return it. Have you actually tried it? Did you get a specific problem?

Comment: No, I didn't try it yet. Just wanted to know, if this is the right way to do it. @0___________ my fault. updated the code. I just wrote it down here quickly.

Comment: @Serge updated -> returning the pointer now

Comment: How do I know the size of the array outside the function?

Comment: Return that as well. Pass in a pointer and have the function store the size in there. Don't be afraid to try things. If you want to know whether something is right or not one of the steps is to build and run it to try.

Comment: If you need to pass the size of the array you could either return a structure that contains a `struct sensorA*` pointer and a `uint8_t` size element or pass the address of a `uint8_t` variable as a pointer argument to deliver the size in addition to the `struct sensorA*` return value.

Comment: You can manage to have the last element of the array a special value that is never in the real data. Something analog to the nul char at the end of a string.

Comment: `struct sensorA array[i] = malloc(i * sizeof(struct sensorA));` is also incorrect. I would suggest to read about pointers & arrays  and the move to this code

Answer (score 1):

This isn't how you design low level embedded systems. Nothing is "created" in run-time - instead you deterministically decide at compile-time what scenarios are allowed to occur. `malloc` is never used, simply because it doesn't make any sense to use it in single-core microcontroller systems.

In this case it sounds like you just need a fixed number of statically allocated data sets corresponding to the maximum number of "sensors" that your program supports. Together with a way to flag that "this sensor is present", a bool flag, a size counter etc.

You can't have unlimited amounts - you need to specify a maximum number supported early on in the design phase, then pick a suitable microcontroller based on the specification.